# I use ema crossover as signal, however deal triggered without crossover

Tags: pine-script

I use ema crossover as signal, however deal triggered at price where no crossover happened...
Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
//@version=5

strategy(title='test', overlay=true, pyramiding=0)

fast = ta.ema(close,50)
mid = ta.ema(close,100)
slow = ta.ema(close,200)

plot(fast, color=color.white)
plot(mid, color=color.yellow)
plot(slow, color=color.red)

if (fast > mid) or (mid > slow) or (fast > slow)
    strategy.entry("Long1", strategy.long, limit=close * 0.99)
if (fast > mid) and (fast > slow)
    strategy.entry("Long3", strategy.long)
    
if fast < mid or mid < slow or fast < slow
    strategy.entry("Short1", strategy.short, limit=close * 1.01)
if fast < mid and fast < slow
    strategy.entry("Short3", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using **Crossover/Crossunder** function instead comparision?

```
fast_up   = ta.crossover(fast,slow)
fast_down = ta.crossunder(fast,slow)
```

Your code will become something like this:

```
//@version=5

strategy(title='test', overlay=true, pyramiding=0)

fast = ta.ema(close,50)
mid  = ta.ema(close,100)
slow = ta.ema(close,200)

plot(fast, color=color.white)
plot(mid, color=color.yellow)
plot(slow, color=color.red)

fast_cross_mid  = ta.crossover(fast,mid)
mid_cross_slow  = ta.crossover(mid,slow)
fast_cross_slow = ta.crossover(fast,slow)

fast_under_mid  = ta.crossunder(fast,mid)
mid_under_slow  = ta.crossunder(mid,slow)
fast_under_slow = ta.crossunder(fast,slow)

if fast_cross_mid or mid_cross_slow or fast_cross_slow
    strategy.entry("Long1", strategy.long, limit=close * 0.99)
if fast_cross_mid and fast_cross_slow
    strategy.entry("Long3", strategy.long)
    
if fast_under_mid or mid_under_slow or fast_under_slow
    strategy.entry("Short1", strategy.short, limit=close * 1.01)
if fast_under_mid and fast_under_slow
    strategy.entry("Short3", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Thank you Turi for your answer!  

The issue I have is that the following part of code didn't work out as I would like it to. I would like to have the slowest cross as a bottomline to avoid against the trend(so when the 50ema and 100ema both corss 200ema, the buy/sell entry will trigger). However the "if" condition with the "and" applies that both conditions have to happen at the same time which is very rare, so it doesn't function as they suppose to.

Comment: if fast_cross_mid and fast_cross_slow
    strategy.entry("Long3", strategy.long)
if fast_under_mid and fast_under_slow
    strategy.entry("Short3", strategy.short)